# how to filter the model where 2 fields are attributed to the user?

Tags: django, filter, django-views, django-queryset

How to filter the model where 2 fields are attributed to the user, where in these 2 fields you can be, how to filter 1 by calling and output all in one variable.

models.py

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    my              = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='My')
    friend          = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='Friend')
    short_message   = models.ForeignKey("Message", related_name="Short_Message")
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

I can be in these 2 fields, but how to pull all 1 at a time, that is, there is a model where I write messages and where I to output through one...

I need to know if such a model with the field my = username and suddenly there is such a model where I will be that friend = username that is I can be in 2 fields how to pull all at once? So that there are not many cycles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **Q**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

```
Conversation.objects.filter(Q(my=user)|Q(friend=user))
```

should work